# Is there a general framework that allows us to compare probabilistic and deterministic algorithms fairly?

Tags: complexity-theory, probability

Many popular QC algorithms are probabilistic in nature, like Grover's, Shor's, QAOA ..etc

For some of these we have formulas that give probabilities of success (like for Grover's and Shor's), and for others that are harder to analyze we estimate these probabilities by testing the algorithm on various problem samples (like for QAOA).

Is there a general framework that we use to compare the performance of either type of probabilistic algorithms against deterministic algorithms to ensure a fair comparison?

Comment: Wall-clock time?

Comment: Do you mean something other than asymptotic computational complexity, or the asymptotic scaling of oracle calls?